# Package dependencies install vs. download

Tags: rpm, dnf, download

I need to find a way to install a rpm on RHEL based systems complete offline, in my test it is AlmaLinux. So I need to download the packages and install the RPMs on the offline machine.

My current process is to download the packages with `dnf -y download $package --resolve --alldeps --downloaddir $localRPMPath`, create a repo with `createrepo` and install it on the offline machine with `dnf -y install $package --nogpgcheck --disablerepo=* --repofrompath localrepo,file://$localRPMPath`

The problem is that in some cases the dependencies are different in the download compared to a normal install. In my case one example is the package "net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-14.el8_2.1.i686". It have a dependency with "rpm-libs". If I do `dnf deplist net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-14.el8_2.1.i686`, I get as dependency rpm-libs-4.14.3-24.el8_6.i686, also with the download command I get this package. If I do an install with `dnf install net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-14.el8_2.1.i686`, it is installing this version 4.14.3-23.el8 of rpm-libs.

If I try to install from my local repo on the same machine I get an error that I can't install this version of rpm-libs, because of a other dependency and it want to install the one I see also if I do a normal install.

How can I tell the download command to better check this or to download even more versions of a package. I don't care if my local repo is X times bigger.

Thanks